# trying to run ruby website locally, says "gemfile states ruby version X, but I have version Y", but then says I already installed Y, and version is X

Tags: ruby-on-rails

As the titles says: trying to run ruby website locally, says "gemfile states ruby version X, but I have version Y", but then says I already installed Y, and version is X.

I am not a ruby dev I am just trying to test this site locally and make some some minor edits. Thank you. [image]

Comment: You have to set the new ruby version `rbenv --help`
e.g: rbenv local 2.7.2
or global e.g: rbenv global 2.7.2

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the ruby version , when you have multiple versions installed.

`version_num - 2.7.2` for your case

For rbenv - `rbenv local version_num` for current directory,
`rbenv global version_num` to change globally.

If you are using rvm you can set it by `rvm use version_num` , this will set it only for that particular terminal. If you want to change the default globally check here https://rvm.io/rubies/default